# How to change JSON's value for List (or array) type?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

```
"title" : { "newTitle" : "Test"}
"tags" : { "newTags" : ["Tag1", "Tag2"] }
```

```cs
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

var json = JObject.Parse(json: json);
var title;  // "Test2" in title
List<string> tags; // "TagA", "TagB", "TagC" in tags


json["title"]["newTitle"] = title; // works well
json["tags"]["newTags"] = tags; // not work
```

I want the JSON result as below:

```
"title" : { "newTitle" : "Test2"}
"tags" : { "newTags" : ["TagA", "TagB", "TagC"] }
```

I want to modify some values of JSON. `int` or `string` worked well. However, the `List` or `Array` does not work.

Please give me a good opinion.

I used a translator. So the writing may be awkward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume your JSON data has defined object template, you can create a class based on your JSON data. With `Newtonsoft.Json`, you deserialize your JSON into an object and next update the object's properties value.

Note: When access object's inner properties for example `Title.NewTitle` and `Tags.NewTags`, you may need to add some null checking for preventing `NullReferenceException`.

**1st solution: Convert to strongly-typed object**

```
public static void Main()
{
    var json = "{\"title\" : { \"newTitle\" : \"Test\"}, \"tags\" : { \"newTags\" : [\"Tag1\", \"Tag2\"] }}";
        
    var inputObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonInput>(json);
    inputObj.Title.NewTitle = "Test2";
    inputObj.Tags.NewTags = new List<string> {"TagA", "TagB", "TagC"};
        
    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(inputObj));
}

public class JsonInput
{
    public Title Title {get;set;}
    public Tags Tags {get;set;}
}

public class Title
{
    public string NewTitle {get;set;}
}

public class Tags
{
    public List<string> NewTags {get;set;}
}
```

[1st solution Code snippets and Output](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jNIDmg)

**2nd solution: With dynamic**

To update array, you need parse your `List<string>` to `JArray` type

```
public static void Main()
{
    var json = "{\"title\" : { \"newTitle\" : \"Test\"}, \"tags\" : { \"newTags\" : [\"Tag1\", \"Tag2\"] }}";
        
    var title = "Test2";  // "Test2" in title
    List<string> tags = new List<string> {"TagA", "TagB", "TagC"}; // "TagA", "TagB", "TagC" in tags

    dynamic root = JObject.Parse(json);
    JObject titleObj = (JObject)root["title"];
    titleObj["newTitle"] = title;
        
    JObject tagsObj = (JObject)root["tags"];
    tagsObj["newTags"] = JArray.FromObject(tags);
        
    Console.WriteLine(root);
}
```

[2nd solution Code snippets and Output](https://dotnetfiddle.net/G7WCs2)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But it's a completely different code from my intention.

I'm going to take some values of JSON that are not fixed and modify them.
JSON has hundreds of variables and cannot create classes like this.

Comment: Hi @이현월, I had added 2nd solution which updates JSON object in dynamic object for `JArray`. You may have a look. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness.
Thanks to you, I was able to broaden my horizons.

Comment: You are welcome. If this solution helps to solve your question, you may mark it as answer as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
     var jsonObject=JObject.Parse(json);

    var newTitle =   "Test2";
    List<string> newTags = new List<string> { "TagA", "TagB", "TagC"};
    
    jsonObject["title"]["newTitle"]= newTitle; 
    jsonObject["tags"]["newTags"]= JArray.FromObject(newTags);
```

result

```
{
  "title": {
    "newTitle": "Test2"
  },
  "tags": {
    "newTags": [
      "TagA",
      "TagB",
      "TagC"
    ]
  }
}
```